# Why can't I use HttpClient to log in to this ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, dotnet-httpclient

There's an ASP.NET website from a third party that requires one to log on. I need to get some data from the website and parse it, so I figured I'd use HttpClient to post the necessary credentials to the website, same as the browser would do it. Then, after that POST request, I figured I'd be able to use the cookie values I received to make further request to the (authorization-only) urls.

I'm down to the point where I can successfully POST the credentials to the login url and receive three cookies: ASP.NET_SessionId, .ASPXAUTH, and a custom value used by the website itself, each with their own values. I figured that since the HttpClient I set up is using an HttpHandler that is using a CookieContainer, the cookies would be sent along with each further request, and I'd remain logged in.

However, this does not appear to be working. If I use the same HttpClient instance to then request one of the secured areas of the website, I'm just getting the login form again. 
The code:

```
        const string loginUri = "https://some.website/login";

        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer, AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate };
        var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var loginRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, loginUri);

        // These form values correspond with the values posted by the browser
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("customercode", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("customerid", "username"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("HandleForm", "Login")
        });

        loginRequest.Content = formContent;

        loginRequest.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393");
        loginRequest.Headers.Referrer = new Uri("https://some.website/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f");
        loginRequest.Headers.Host = "some.website";
        loginRequest.Headers.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
        loginRequest.Headers.CacheControl = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
        loginRequest.Headers.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("nl-NL");
        loginRequest.Headers.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate");
        loginRequest.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(loginRequest);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(loginUri));
```

When using the proper credentials, cookies contains three items, including a .ASPXAUTH cookie and a session id, which suggests that the login succeeded. However:

```
        var text = await client.GetStringAsync("https://some.website/secureaction");
```

...this just returns the login form again, and not the content I get when I log in using the browser and navigate to /secureaction.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** here's the complete request my application is making and the request chrome is making. They are identical, save for the cookie values. I ran them through windiff: the lines marked <! are the lines sent by my application, the ones marked !> are sent by Chrome.

```
GET https://some.website/secureaction 
Connection: keep-alive  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br 
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1  
Host: some.website  
Accept-Language:nl-NL, 
>> nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Accept: text/html, 
>> application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Cookie: 
<!      customCookie=7CF190C0; 
<!          .ASPXAUTH=37D61E47(shortened for readability); 
<!      ASP.NET_SessionId=oqwmfwahpvf0qzpiextx0wtb 
!>      ASP.NET_SessionId=kn4t4rmeu2lfrgozjjga0z2j;          
!>          customCookie=8D43E263; 
!>          .ASPXAUTH=C2477BA1(shortened for readability)
```

The HttpClient application get a 302 referral to /login, Chrome gets a 200 response containing the requested page.

Comment: Have you asked the owner of said website if a) They support this method of working and b) how to achieve it?

Comment: Try with fiddler running and compare a browser request with what your code is doing.

Comment: @Jamiec It works in the browser, and the browser is just sending GET and POST requests, same as the code.

Comment: @Bas no, HttpClient is *not* the same as a browser.

Comment: @Bas but how does you code request look when compared to browser after receiving the cookies?

Comment: @Jamiec I didn't say HttpClient is the same as a browser.

Comment: It may not just be Cookie, there may be other hidden information which the website may be expecting and on not finding them it may redirect your back to Login page.

Comment: Did you try following Alex's advice? The site isn't going to know whether it's a browser or HttpClient. All it cares is that the requests look like what it expects. That's why you need to use Fiddler to inspect the requests.

Comment: I used fiddler to check, and on the request to /secureaction it is sending .ASPXAUTH, ASP.NET_SessionId and the site's custom cookie both on the browser request and on the HttpClient request. The only difference appears to be that on the browser, I get an HTTP 200 result, whereas on HttpClient I get an HTTP 302 result that redirects back to /login.

Comment: I think I figured it out: my application starts with a POST to /login, but when I try it via chrome I first have to navigate to /login before posting the form, so it does a GET /login first. It seems that the ASP.NET session id it receives there is essential for the rest. I've done a simple GET request to /login before doing the POST in my application, and now I don't get the 302 anymore.

Comment: @Bas hello! got the same problem I think, can you post answer how to do that?

Comment: @Bas oh well I compared with data in fiddler and made up all headers like there and now I made my code work!

Comment: It'd be nice to share your code or some brief info for the benefit of others who are having the same question as yours.

Comment: @AmirNo-Family Good idea, added an answer with the final code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here's how I eventually made it work. I had to do a simple GET request to /login first, and *then* do a POST with the login credentials. I don't recall what value exactly is being set by that GET (I assume a cookie with some encoded value the server wants), but the HttpClient takes care of the cookies anyway, so it just works. Here's the final, working code:

```
    const string loginUri = "https://some.website/login";

    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() 
    { 
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer, 
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate 
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // First do a GET to the login page, allowing the server to set certain 
    // required cookie values.
    var initialGetRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.GET, loginUri);
    await client.SendAsync(initialGetRequest);

    var loginRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, loginUri);

    // These form values correspond with the values posted by the browser
    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("customercode", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("customerid", "username"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("HandleForm", "Login")
    });

    loginRequest.Content = formContent;

    loginRequest.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393");
    loginRequest.Headers.Referrer = new Uri("https://some.website/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f");
    loginRequest.Headers.Host = "some.website";
    loginRequest.Headers.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
    loginRequest.Headers.CacheControl = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
    loginRequest.Headers.AcceptLanguage.ParseAdd("nl-NL");
    loginRequest.Headers.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate");
    loginRequest.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(loginRequest);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(loginUri));
```